# Text file with different data types into structure array

Tags: c, arrays, structure, file-processing

I have to parse a text file with 3 different data types. I want it to be saved in a structure array with three members. My text file look like this:

```
A B 45.78965
A C 35.46731
B C 46.78695
```

The program that I'm reading it with is the following and it does not work.
What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct gra {
    char from;
    char to;
    double w;
};

int main ()
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("graph.txt", "r"); 
    int i = 0;
    while (!feof(fp)) {
        fscanf(fp, "%[^\t]", &graph[i].from, &graph[i].to, &graph[i].w);
        i++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
 }
```

Comment: You don't **print** any thing. So no output.

Comment: Your program doesn't do anything other than read the file in and then close. What did you expect it to do?

Comment: okay, so what do I need to do? I just want to save the file to the array. :(

Comment: To check,if your file data is saved to array or not,just print your array after `fclose(fp)`. :)

Comment: @AqToh, welcome to SO. "What should I do?" is not the type of questions that this site is dedicated for. We are here for concrete technical questions.

Comment: Have you tried to make a simple [Hello World](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello_world_program) program? Then you should know how to print things. Also, you're not scanning three items with that format, only one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your problems is that you're reading using `%[^\t]`, which reads strings, and store the result to variables that are not character arrays (two characters and a double).

Although it's not clear from your question, it seems that the lines of your input contain two characters and one real number separated by one tab character.  If that is so, you should use the following `fscanf` to read them:

```
fscanf(fp, "%c\t%c\t%lf\n", &graph[i].from, &graph[i].to, &graph[i].w);
```

If you are not sure what exactly separates your fields and you want to allow any amount of white space in between and also extra white space in the beginning and end of the line, then use:

```
fscanf(fp, " %c %c%lf\n", &graph[i].from, &graph[i].to, &graph[i].w);
```

that is, use an extra space in the format before each `"%c"` to explicitly skip white space.

Your code has also a couple of other problems:

1. You are using `feof` to check for end of file.  This will usually not work well if you're not reading the file character by character.  Instead, you should check if your `fscanf` returned 3, that is, if it successfully read the three things that you wanted it to read.
2. You are missing a definition of array `graph`.

I'm adding the complete code that I'd write for doing the parsing:

```
#include"stdio.h"
#define MAX 100

struct {
  char from, to;
  double w;
} graph[MAX];

int main ()
{
  FILE *fp = fopen("graph.txt", "rt");  
  for (int i=0; i<MAX; i++)
    if (fscanf(fp, " %c %c%lf\n", &graph[i].from, &graph[i].to, &graph[i].w) < 3)
      break;
  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes thank you for the comments. My question is how can I save those data types into the structure array? I can print the data using the function printf("%c %c %lf",a.from,a.to,a.w) but i can't save those data into my array. should I use fget function to reading every single character in the text file?

Comment: You will be saving your data to your array if you use a proper `fscanf`.  I'm adding the complete code to my answer, to help you.

Comment: +1 for the sample code.

Comment: sorry last question. what is the meaning of "rt" in the code? and why did you use 3 in fscanf? :D thank you so much! :D

Comment: The "rt" denotes that it is a text file (e.g. Automatically converts newlines between different OSs). You should use it when you know that your files contain text.

Comment: The magic number 3 is already explained in the answer: "Instead, you should check if your fscanf returned 3, that is, if it successfully read the three things that you wanted it to read."  Check the returned value in the man page of scanf for more.